# Import Data From CSV Using Control File Is failing

Tags: hana

I am importing CSV file into HANA server using control file using hdbsql and for that purpose i am using IMPORT FROm CSVs statements into control file. My HANA Studio file import is working fine but when i am trying to import through hdbsql using control file as input , my import is failing for no reason, no error.
My CSV file is record delimited {CR}{LF} and i am using '\r\n' as record delimited separator and this file is UTF-16LE encoded.

Comment: The `IMPORT FROM` is a server-side import and the client you use to trigger it, `hdbsql` in this case, has *no* impact on it. Please check the indexserver trace file for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to @LarsBr. comment, you also need to be careful on where you will load the file from.

It needs to be in a specific directory or you will need to adjust the configuration to use a different one.

Here is a tutorial I wrote to explain that: https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/mlb-hxe-import-data-sql-import.html

There is a "ERROR LOG" option available as well documented here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/latest/en-US/20f712e175191014907393741fadcb97.html